Azure AD B2C using MSAL in .NET framework application for Excel Add-Ins
We created a VTSO COM add-in (written in C#) for the Excel Windows desktop application. We plan on selling this add-in to a variety of users (personal, work and school accounts) and managing access to the add-in through an Azure AD B2C tenant. Our intention is that when a user launches our add-in in Excel that they are first prompted to login with their Microsoft account. This then connects to our Azure AD B2C tenant, and if the user is listed within our tenant they are successfully authenticated (and granted access to the add-in).
As of right now, our main priority is to successfully authenticate users (interactively) in our Azure B2C tenant. This means that we are trying to make sure both our code base and the Azure side setup is correct. As of now, we are facing the issue where when we run the code with both a redirect URI and with an Authority we think are correct, we are receiving script errors. When we remove the redirect URI in the code, we get a blank sign in screen, but when we omit the Authority, we authenticate into our tenant correctly, but without triggering our user flows. When we try to change these values, we get an exception saying the URI is incorrect. We have tested our user flows in our Azure B2C tenant and believe they are set up correctly. We have attached below the code we are currently running, and a screenshot of the script error.
/////////////// THISADDIN.CS ///////////////////
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace authtest_addin
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Authenticate.isAuthorizedUser = false;
            Authenticate.AppCreation();
            Task.Run(async () => await Authenticate.RunAuthentication());
            //MessageBox.Show(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.UserName);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }
        
        #endregion
    }
}

/////////////// AUTHENICATE.CS ////////////////////////////////
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client.NativeInterop;

namespace authtest_addin
{
    internal class Authenticate
    {
        public static bool isAuthorizedUser;
        private static IPublicClientApplication app;
        private static readonly string clientID = "82d76b60-b6c5-4cb4-ac05-df77bece9feb";
        private static readonly string tenantID = "c7afce06-4b73-4f1f-b069-9d611042a736";
        public static string SignInPolicy = "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn";  // Replace with your user flow name
        private static readonly string Tenant = "khordeveloperb2c.onmicrosoft.com";
        public static string AuthorityBase = $"https://khordeveloperb2c.b2clogin.com/tfp/{Tenant}/";
        private static readonly string redirectURI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";

        public static async Task RunAuthentication()
        {
            await AuthenticateUser();

            if (isAuthorizedUser)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Authorized");
                Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.authStatus.Label = "User Status: Authorized";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unauthorized");
                Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.authStatus.Label = "User Status: Unauthorized";
            }

            Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.PerformLayout(); // Refresh Ribbon to update auth label
        }
        public static void AppCreation()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AppCreation Start");

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientID)
                .WithB2CAuthority($"{AuthorityBase}{SignInPolicy}")
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectURI)
                .Build();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AppCreation Finish");
        }
        
        private static async Task AuthenticateUser()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("AuthenticateUser Start");
            // Variables (Pre Authentication)
            AuthenticationResult result;
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "openid", "offline_access" };

            // Retrieve accounts
            var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

            try
            {
                // Silent Authentication
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Try Silent Auth Flow");
                result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                  .ExecuteAsync();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Finish Silent Auth Flow");
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Try Interactive Auth Flow");
                    foreach (var account in accounts)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("account: " + account.ToString());
                    }
                    
                    // Interactive Authentication
                    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount).ExecuteAsync();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Finish Interactive Auth Flow");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Failed Auth");
                    // Failed Authentication
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    isAuthorizedUser = false;
                    return;
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Authenticated");
        isAuthorizedUser = true;
        return;
        }
    }
} 



The script error likely occurs due to incorrect configuration of the redirect URI or authority. Ensure the redirect URI (https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient) is registered in your Azure AD B2C application, and double-check the authority URL for your B2C tenant and user flow. Update your authority URL to include /v2.0/ after your tenant-specific login domain.
